# Binding form action to controller method

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to bind form action(which has id related to a model/table record) to controller method.

My web.php has

```
Route::post('/rejectControlTransfer/{id}', 'ControlTransferController@rejectControlTransfer')->name('controltransfers.rejectTransfer');
```

My form has

```
<form id='form_process_rejectControl' action="{{route('controltransfers.rejectTransfer', [$controlTransferId])}}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

And my controller has

```
public function rejectControlTransfer(Request $request, ControlTransfer $controlTransfer)
{
   dd($controlTransfer->id);
}
```

I am trying to bind ControlTransfer $controlTransfer with the actual id passed so that when I try get value of $controlTransfer->id or $controlTransfer->name would give me their values.

Current I am not getting any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `id` in the route `'/rejectControlTransfer/{id}` then you can only access it through `$id` variable in your controller, which is a raw variable `int`.

Besides that, your action's 'route' function is not used correctly, you need to put `'id'` as your `key`, like:

```
route('controltransfers.rejectTransfer', ['id' => $controlTransferId])
```

However, if your `ControlTransfer` is a model, you can use [**Model Binding**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding). By:

```
Route::post('/rejectControlTransfer/{controlTransfer}', 'ControlTransferController@rejectControlTransfer')->name('controltransfers.rejectTransfer');

<form id='form_process_rejectControl' action="{{route('controltransfers.rejectTransfer', ['controlTransfer' => $controlTransferId])}}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>

public function rejectControlTransfer(Request $request, ControlTransfer $controlTransfer)
{
   dd($controlTransfer->id);
}
```

Disclaimer: Above code is untested.